# Parenting a child object to parent in Unity

Tags: unity, blender, makehuman

I am making an 3d Tennis game in Unity 5.0. I have made 3d model of the Tennis player in Makehuman and have successfully imported it to Blender and Unity.

I want to add an tennis racket in the hand on my Makehuman model. So what should the strategy be?

Should I add the tennis racket to the Makehuman character in Blender as the child of the Makehuman model and then animating it or is there a simple way to do that in Unity in the game.

Answer (score 2):

Make the racket as child of a finger or hand bone that will translate/move as you want.

Animate the humanoid without racket but keep the moves of hand as if there is a racket in hand.

Go to the skeletal rig under your model prefab object. Drag and drop the racket under your chosen bone. We put rifle with forearm.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply SP. How to child an object with an particular bone in Unity

Comment: Please check edit.